# Combobox/Dropdownbutton in Datagridview Windows Forms Doesn't Show DropDown List

Tags: winforms, drop-down-menu, visual-studio-2022, .net-4.7.2

VS 2022 / Windows .Net-Enabled Forms App / .Net Framework 4.7.2
Using strictly the Toolbox controls and object properties (no coding).

I've created hundreds of VB Windows applications with dropdown columns in datagridviews and have never encountered this problem before.

The datagridview is bound to an SQL datasource using the standard process of dropping a datasource onto the splitpanel container on a tab control object.  Changed the 'status' column to a dropdownlist and added it's SQL datasource using the VS wizard (like I've done a hundred times).

When the window loads in debug the datagridview data loads, the dropdown list data loads (confirmed by checking the binding source count, but the dropdown itself does absolutely nothing when I click on it.  The first value from the DS appears, "New", but when I click the down arrow, no other values appear in a dropdown list.  There is no dropdown action.

I've confirmed that the ddl is not disabled.  I've deleted everything and started over from scratch, but get the same result.

Is this a VS2022 bug?  Do I have to revert back to using VS2017?

Comment: I thought it might be because I was using the VS Dev Essentials version of VS, so I purchased VS 2022 Pro.  Did not resolve the issue.